# Categorical occurence counting among subjects

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have binned reaction time (IRIBP15 in the df) into categories. I'd like to count, for each participant, the number of reaction time in each categories. I tried :

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['Subject','Ctg']).df['Ctg'].count().reset_index()
```

but it is returning me 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'df', and I'm not sure about my line.

```
     Subject  IRIBP15  Category
0         50.0    332.0  375
1         50.0    206.0  225
2         50.0    251.0  275
3         50.0    478.0  525
4         50.0    382.0  425
...        ...      ...  ...
55291     73.0    165.0  175
55292     73.0    -83.0  -75
55293     73.0    142.0  175
55294     73.0    102.0  125
55295     73.0     -5.0   25
```

I'd like to have an output with the subject id (number), each category (375, 225...for example), and the number of reaction time observed in each category.
I hope I'm clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state in your problem that reaction time is indicated by `IRIBP15`, so you need to use `IRIBP15` column after groupby.

```py
print(df.groupby(['Subject','Category'])['IRIBP15'].count())

'''
Subject  Category
50.0      225        1
          275        1
          375        1
          425        1
          525        1
73.0     -75         1
          25         1
          125        1
          175        2
'''
```